# Error in processing entity Equipment unable to create entity object

Tags: c#, assets, infor-eam

I am Attempting to use AddGISAsset from the infor-eam toolkit:

> MP0385_AddGISAsset_001

I am receiving this error:

> Error in processing entity Equipment unable to create entity object.

Here is the code:

```
public string addGisAsset()
        {

            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.AddGISAssetService getservice = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.AddGISAssetService();
            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.MP0385_AddGISAsset_001 getrequest = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.MP0385_AddGISAsset_001();
            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.MP0385_AddGISAsset_001_Result getresult = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.MP0385_AddGISAsset_001_Result();

            string desc = null;
            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.EQUIPMENTID_Type asset = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.EQUIPMENTID_Type();
            asset.EQUIPMENTCODE = "2000000";
            asset.ORGANIZATIONID = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.ORGANIZATIONID_Type();
            asset.ORGANIZATIONID.ORGANIZATIONCODE = _orgcode;
            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.QUANTITY X = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.QUANTITY();
            MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.QUANTITY Y = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.QUANTITY();
            X.VALUE = 50;
            X.NUMOFDEC = "2";
            X.SIGN = "+";
            X.UOM = "feet";
            Y.VALUE = 75;
            Y.NUMOFDEC = "2";
            Y.SIGN = "+";
            Y.UOM = "feet";

            getrequest.GISAsset = new MP0385_AddGISAsset_001.GISAsset();
            getrequest.GISAsset.ASSETID = asset;
            getrequest.GISAsset.XLOCATION = X;
            getrequest.GISAsset.YLOCATION = Y;
            getrequest.GISAsset.GISLAYER = "0";

            Datastream.EWS.Session sess = new Datastream.EWS.Session(_userid, _passwd, "*", _url, _tenant, false);

            // Start Request
            sess.PrepareServiceRequest(getservice);

            // Call Web Service and get result
            getresult = getservice.AddGISAssetOp(getrequest);

            // Extract Description (just for testing, we dont need this)
            desc = getresult.ResultData.GISAsset.ASSETID.EQUIPMENTCODE;

            // Close Up/Dispose
            sess.CompleteServiceRequest(getservice);
            sess.Dispose();
            return desc;

        }
```

PLEASE:  Can someone create a new tag for stackoverflow.com called "INFOR-EAM"

Here is the product:

http://www.infor.com/solutions/eam/

Answer (score 0):

Solved, turns out that error means that the Equipment Code does not exist:

asset.EQUIPMENTCODE = "2000000";

Very misleading error message but was able to solve it.